# Answering an essay question "assess the impact" or "analyse the impact"

Tags: structure, essay

If an essay question states "assess/evaluate/analyse the impact of X on Y", does this allow for a discussion of how Z impacts Y?

For example, if the essay question is "Assess the impact of Deism on the authority of the Church", can you also devote a paragraph or two on the impact of other philosophies such as Rationalism, Empiricism and Skepticism in the essay, or would these be considered off-topic?

Example topic sentence for a paragraph: "While Deism had a significant impact on the the authority of the Church, other philosophies at the time had a similar effect."

Comment: It would be off-topic. They seem to want your knowledge of how X impacted Z, but also what makes X unique from everything else that impacted Z.

Comment: @SirenKing Agreed, and you should make that an answer. Answers do not have to be long.

Comment: @SirenKing Doesn't that imply pointing out what makes it unique *compared to other things*? (A full "discussion" would probably be too much, but a sentence, like the one given in the example, here or there might be okay.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be off-topic. They seem to want your knowledge of how X impacted Z, but also what makes X unique from everything else that impacted Z
(Made an answer by request)